# Qt 5.0 Json encoding

Tags: c++, json, qt, qt5, qjson

Im using qt 5.0 and its support such classes as QJsonObject QJsonDocument and QJsonArray. In my programm i need to serialize json array and convert it to qstring/qbytearray but i didn't found any serialize or encode methods in those classes. Is there any way i can serialize data using included qt 5.0. libs?  I found this example:

```
QVariant id(1), name("John Doe");
QJsonObject json;

json["Name"] = name.toString();
json.insert("id", id.toInt());
```

But i can't find how i can make an array from it.

Comment: I've never used qt myself, so I'm not posting this as an answer. I did a quick search on documentation [http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qjsonobject.html](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qjsonobject.html) and it looks like you can create an array like this: `json.insert("id", QJsonArray());` The QJsonValue class has a conversion constructor from a QJsonArray. Of course, you'd want to setup the QJsonArray instead of inserting a default one.

Comment: but how do i convert full json object with all keys/and arrays to string?

Comment: See [http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qjsondocument.html](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qjsondocument.html). Looks like you need to instantiate a QJsonDocument and get its raw data. `QJsonDocument Doc; Doc.SetObject(json); int Size; const char* RawJson = Doc.rawData(&Size);`

Comment: I have tried it like so:    `QVariant name("John Doe");
     QJsonObject json;
     json.insert("name", QJsonValue::fromVariant(name));

     QJsonDocument Doc; Doc.setObject(json); int Size;

     const char* RawJson = Doc.rawData(&Size);

     QString t = QString::fromLatin1(RawJson);

     qDebug() << t;`   I get RawData = "qbjs" and t = "qbjs"

Comment: My bad.  It looks like `rawData()` returns the binary JSON format.  Try `QByteArray ByteArray = Doc.toJson()` instead. Documentation: Converts the QJsonDocument to a UTF-8 encoded JSON document.

Comment: @Chris Cooper, Doc.toJson return void not QbyteArray. You must use Doc.toBinaryArray

Answer (score 0):

Question closed. Use QJsonDocument::toJson to get data from QJsonObject.

Answer (score 0):

I think the secret is that when serializing to JSON, Qt writes out a UTF-8 binary encoded version of the text into a `QByteArray`.  You can recover the string using [`QString::fromUtf8`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromUtf8).  Also, even though `toJson` writes out a `QByteArray` it is not a true binary representation; as I just mentioned, it is the bytes of the UTF-8 encoded **string** representation of the JSON.  For binary serialization you must use either Qt's own [`QJsonDocument::toBinaryData`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#toBinaryData) or find a BSON library.

## Text serialization

Use [`QJsonDocument::toJson`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#toJson-1) to serialize as text via a [`QString`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html), and [`QJsonDocument::fromJson`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#fromJson) to deserialize from text.

***Tip***:  Consider passing the `QJsonDocument::Compact` [format option](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#JsonFormat-enum) to get compact JSON output during serialization.

#### To QString

```
QString json = QString::fromUtf8(doc.toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact));
```

#### From QString

```
QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(json);
```

## Binary serialization

Use [`QJsonDocument::toBinaryData`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#toBinaryData) to serialize as binary via a [`QByteArray`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html), and [`QJsonDocument::fromBinaryData`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#fromBinaryData) to deserialize from binary.

***Caveat***: The binary format used by the above functions is Qt's own binary format (qbjs) so may not be suitable for interoperation with other binary formats such as [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/).  For that, you might want to look into choosing [a BSON implementation](http://bsonspec.org/implementations.html).

#### To QByteArray

```
QByteArray bytes = doc.toBinaryData();
```

#### From QByteArray

```
QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromBinaryData(bytes);
```